# jQuery SlideDown only if another `ul` is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've an unordered list.

```
<div class="categories-list">
    <ul class="display_categories">
        <li>
            <a class="title"><span><b>1</b></span></a> 
            <ul class="display_subcategories">
                <li><a>22</a></li>
                <li><a>22</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="title"><span><b>1</b></span></a> 
            <ul class="display_subcategories">
                <li><a>22</a></li>
                <li><a>22</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want that when a user clicks on any category, its sub-category should slidedown and whenever the same category is clicked, nothing should happen. Here's my jQuery

```
$('.display_subcategories').hide()
$('.title').click(function(){
    $('.display_categories').children().children('ul').slideUp('fast');
    $(this).next().slideDown('fast');
})
```

but what happens is that upon clicking on the already slideDown category, it again slides up and then slides down.

Here is the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z62Lprn2/) link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `slideDown` the current submenu, then use `not()` to `slideUp()` all except the current, like this:

```
$('.display_subcategories').hide()
$('.title').click(function() {
    var $submenu = $(this).next().slideDown('fast');
    $('.display_categories').find('> li > ul').not($submenu).slideUp('fast');
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/8ed4mjqh/)

Note also the use of `find()` with the descendant selector over chained `children()` calls.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. May I ask whats the difference between your previous answer and you current one?

Comment: This one is more efficient as it uses less selectors, and it's shorter.

Comment: Thanks.. Request you to post both the solutions. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    $('.display_subcategories').hide();

    $('.title').click(function(){
       if(!$(this).hasClass('down')){
          $('.title').removeClass('down');
          $('.display_categories').children().children('ul').slideUp('fast');
          $(this).next().slideDown('fast');
          $(this).addClass('down');
      }  
  })
```

[Updated JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jitendratiwari/z62Lprn2/5/)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest letting CSS manage your animations by triggering or disabling classes. A simple example would be adding the `.active` class to an open `<ul>`, and the following CSS:

```
.display_subcategories { max-height: 0; overflow: hidden; transition: all 300ms; }
.display_subcategories.active { max-height: 50px; }
```

Here is [a modified JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e0ntemwb/) with my suggestion.